# How to check if point is in elliptical sector without float-point arithmetic?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, integer-programming

How can I check whether point lies in elliptical sector without float-point arithmetic if I know `a` and `b` from the ellipse equation, start and end angles of the sector and `x`, `y` coordinates of the point.

Comment: What is an "elliptical sector"? Are $a,b$ and the $x,y$ coordinates given in "float-point"?

Comment: Elliptical sector is a part of ellipse, it is determined by start and end angles. `a`, `b` and points' coordinates given as integers.

Comment: Okay. How are the angles given? Integers also? Slopes of lines from the origin? Can you give an example of what you are given?

Comment: Yeah, actually I just have a bitmap and ellipse on it. I iterate all border points of that ellipse and want to determine whether point belogs to this sector or not. For example, angles could be 0 and 45.

Comment: Getting closer. Angle is integer degrees. Okay, I guess ellipse is $(x/a)^2+(y/b)^2 = 1.$ Should be enough now.

Comment: Yes, this equation is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is to check if the inequalities
$$ (x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 \le 1, \tag{1}$$
$$ \tan(t_1) \le y/x \le \tan(t_2). \tag{2}$$
hold for the integers $\, x, y \,$ where $\, a,b>0 \,$
are positive integers and $\,t_1, t_2\,$ are angles
in degrees (or other units). We suppose we have available
sine/cosine tables
$\, S(t) = \sin(t)\, r, \quad C(t) = \cos(t)\, r \,$ where
$\, r>0 \,$ is an integer radius of a circle. The first
 inequality is equivalent to
$$ b^2 x^2 + a^2 y^2 \le a^2b^2 \tag{3}$$
while the second is equivalent to
$$ S(t_1)x \le  C(t_1)y, \quad C(t_2)y \le S(t_2)x \tag{4}$$ 
but we have to be careful if $\, x<0, y<0 \,$ or
 $\,C(t_1)<0,\, C(t_2)<0 \,$ and special case code to deal with that is probably the best idea.